# SQLite3: Failing to import CSV on Mac

Tags: csv, sqlite

I'm a newbie to sqlite3 and I'm trying to play around with some data that I got my hands on.

I'm currently running into the problem in which I cannot even create my table in my shell. I'm trying to run

```
.mode csv
.import filename tab1
```

But I'm getting this error

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(...) failed: duplicate column name: B-
```

Since I'm importing a .csv file, I thought that perhaps I do have a duplicate in my column names but they all seem to be distinct to me. Can someone point me in the right direction? I would really appreciate it :-)

Here is a short excerpt of my .csv file:

```
SID,Name,Cohort,Email,Gender,Ethnicity,Major,Grades,More grades,Last grades,Not sure,,
24239361,name1,Cohort 1-Fall 2013,name1@email.com,Female,Chinese,CS,B,C+,B-,B-,,
24474707,name2,Cohort 1-Fall 2013,name2@email.com,Male,Chinese,CS,B,B+,B-,B-,,
24266062,name3,Cohort 1-Fall 2013,name3@email.com,Male,White,CS,B-,B-,C,B ,,
```

UPDATE: 
Edited my csv file to now only be:

```
SID,Name,Cohort
24239361,Name1,Cohort 1-Fall 2013
24474707,Name2,Cohort 1-Fall 2013
24266062,Name3,Cohort 1-Fall 2013
22181134,Name4,Cohort 1-Fall 2013
```

And when I import it and do .schema, I get this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
"SID" TEXT,
"Name" TEXT,
24239361" TEXT,
"Name1" TEXT,
24474707" TEXT,l 2013
"Name2" TEXT,
24266062" TEXT,l 2013
"Name3" TEXT,
22181134" TEXT,l 2013
"Name4" TEXT,
 24527147" TEXT,l 2013
```

This is really strange because I'm skipping over the header column "Cohort" and instead reading all of my following lines to columns

Comment: I'd guess that your line ends are wrong. How exactly did you create that .csv file? And try updating to the latest SQLite tools package.

Comment: It was originally an excel file that I saved to a .csv file. Would that be a source of the problem?

Comment: There might be invisible control characters in your .csv file. And which version of `sqlite3` are you using?

Comment: Run `create table bar(x);`, then `.mode list` and `.import filename bar`, then show the output of `select hex(x) from bar limit 2;`.

Comment: Currently using QLite version 3.13.0. My output from running that is a ton of text "5349442C4E616D652C436F686F72740D32343233393336312C416C6C69736F6E20436F72696E6E65205965652C436F686F727420312D46616C6C20323031330D32343437343730372C416E74686F6E792048616E204C696E204875616E67202872657175657374656420746F2062652072656D6F7665642066726F6D206C69737473657276292C436F686F727420312D46616C6C20323031330D32343236363036322C44616E69656C20476F6C64626572672C436F686F727420312D46616C6C20323031330D32323138313133342C45726963204C..."

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue *exactly*, but when I try with your sample data I get the following not-quite-identical error:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(...) failed: duplicate column name:
```

And the reason for that is those two commas at the end of your first line (representing the columns of the new table). SQLite tries to make two columns with blank names and fails on the second. The solution is to either remove those commas from every line of the file, or to give those fields valid column names.

I wasn't able to specifically reproduce your issue, but it looks like SQLite is not seeing that first line for some reason or another and is trying to set the columns up based on one of the next lines (which have multiple fields with value `B-`, causing the same issue as above). You'll need to track down why that's happening. Alternatively, you can create the table first, and remove the column heading line from the file before you import it:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (SID INTEGER, Name TEXT, ...);
.mode csv
.import filename tab1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I removed the extra commas at the end and I'm currently trying to figure out why it's trying to create columns from my 2nd line. It seems like SQLite3 is interpreting all of my lines as columns for some reason. Is it a format error?

Comment: Upon debugging, I found that for some reason my "Cohort" column is being ignored and it's continuing to read the rest of my lines as more columns....

Answer (score 2):

The `sqlite3` tool expects the new-line characters in CSV files to be CR+LF (as specified in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)).

Your file looks like this:

```
00000000: 53 49 44 2c 4e 61 6d 65 2c 43 6f 68 6f 72 74 0d  SID,Name,Cohort.
00000010: 32 34 32 33 39 33 36 31 2c 41 6c 6c 69 73 6f 6e  24239361,Xxxxxxx
00000020: 20 43 6f 72 69 6e 6e 65 20 59 65 65 2c 43 6f 68   Xxxxxxx Xxx,Coh
00000030: 6f 72 74 20 31 2d 46 61 6c 6c 20 32 30 31 33 0d  ort 1-Fall 2013.
00000040: 32 34 34 37 34 37 30 37 2c 41 6e 74 68 6f 6e 79  24474707,Xxxxxxx
...
```

This file has Mac line endings (only CR), which would be valid for a normal text file.

You can manually change the row separator after setting CSV mode:

```
.mode csv
.sep , \r
```

Comment: I'm currently using a Mac so if I have Mac line endings it should be fine? Is there more to it that I'm not understanding?